# ORA-08103: object no longer exists in .net

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, rdbms, global-temp-tables

I have a global temporary table (on commit delete rows) called "GLOBAL_T" and a stored procedure which takes a SYS_REFCURSOR as an OUTPUT parameter.

So you can think a stored procedure like this:

```
PROCEDURE test (POT_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN

--TO FILL THE GTT, CALL ANOTHER PROCEDURE
--BTW, FOLLOWING PROCEDURE HAS NO COMMIT
A_SCHEMA_NAME.A_PACKAGE_NAME.ANOTHER_PROCEDURE();

OPEN POT_CURSOR FOR
SELECT STH FROM GLOBAL_T, BUNCH_OF_OTHER_TABLES B
WHERE B.BLABLA = GLOBAL_T.BLABLA
AND B.BUNCH_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS = T.OTHER_COLUMNS;

END;
```

The problem is when I call the procedure within a pl/sql block it works fine. But when I call the procedure from .NET it gives me **ORA-08103: object no longer exists**

The calls are exactly the same. Since the business logic behind the procedures are massive, I tried to simplify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is gone after I altered my global temporary table. I made a simple change. Instead of using "on commit delete rows" I used "**on commit preserve rows**"

Comment: That helped me too - although the call for temporary table is in the same procedure, one line above where exception was thrown. Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a look at oracle-support and Doc ID 8103.1. Often this exception is raised when other sessions are executing ddl statements against tables or indexes while your sql is running - i.e. truncate table or index rebuilds.

Advice: trace ddl by setting

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET enable_ddl_logging=TRUE scope=memory
```

Then run your code hopefully with exception, and later check the diagnostic dir for file ddl_.log. It should contain ddl statements along with a timestamp.

Hope it helps - and don't forget to reset ddl-logging

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET enable_ddl_logging=FALSE scope=memory
```

Comment: The problem is gone after I altered my global temporary table. 
I made a simple change. Instead of using "on commit delete rows" I used "on commit preserve rows"

Comment: OK. This indicates, that somewhere between the call of test() and the processing of the returned pot_cursor a commit/rollback is executed. This will raise the ORA-08103 because the datablocks of the gtt the refcursor points to have been deleted. Try it with your PL/SQL-Code. It's easy to reproduce.